# Movie data set analysis using PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have the following data set for a movie database:

Ratings: UserID, MovieID, Rating :: Movies: MovieID, Title :: Users: UserID, Gender, Age

Now I have to JOIN the above 3 datasets and determine which movie has the highest rating among females and lowest rating among males, and vice versa.
I have done the JOIN:

```
myusers = LOAD '/user/cloudera/movies/input/users.dat' 
  USING PigStorage(':') 
  AS (user:int, n1, gender:chararray, n2, age:int);

ratings = LOAD '/user/cloudera/movies/input/ratings.dat' 
  USING PigStorage(':') 
  AS (user:int, n1, movie:int, n2, rating:int);

movies = LOAD '/user/cloudera/movies/input/movies.dat' 
  USING PigStorage(':') 
  AS (movie:int,n1,title:chararray);

data = JOIN ratings BY user, myusers BY user;
data2= JOIN data BY ratings::movie, movies BY movie;
```

But after this I am running into many issues such as "ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output" when I try to print columns from data2. Any ideas to help me accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

After the following step

```
data = JOIN ratings BY user, myusers BY user;
```

Create two datasets one for male and another for female by using gender as the filter.Order the dataset and get the max and min for both the datasets.

```
male = FILTER data by gender == 'M'; -- Use the gender value for male
female = FILTER data by gender == 'F';
m_max = LIMIT (ORDER male by rating DESC) 1;
f_max = LIMIT (ORDER female by rating DESC) 1;
m_min = LIMIT (ORDER male by rating ASC) 1;
f_min = LIMIT (ORDER female by rating ASC) 1;
```